# Replace one of the view controllers of tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on an application that uses a UITabBarController and I've assigned 3 ViewControllers to the UITabBarController.

I'm building this application programmatically. In AppDelegate I created a UITabBarController. I then create a UINavigationController and set the rootViewController as the UITabBarController.

I then set window rootViewController as the UINavigationController

Here's my code from AppDelegate:

```
    let mainViewcontroller = TabBarController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewcontroller)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Now I created instances of my 3 viewControllers and added them to the viewController list of the UITabBarController. What I want to do now is to display on tap of a button a new different viewController that is not one of the 3 viewControllers that are assigned to the TabBar. I have been able to achieve this by using the present(ViewController) method:

```
    newVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NewViewController())
    self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem that I'm having is that I want the viewController to be displayed behind the UITabBarController. When I use the present() from above the viewController is displayed over the viewController and the TabBar. I've tried presenting the viewController by doing self.tabBarController.present() and window.rootViewController.present and I get the same result which is the TabBar is gone. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = yourDesiredViewController` index

Comment: The assignment above expects an Int, not a viewController.

Comment: you need to pass your desiredViewControllerIndex, sorry in my previous comment I had separated index is a typo error

Comment: I understand what you mean now and I've should have been more clear in my question. What I want to do is display a new viewController that is not one of the viewControllers that I've assigned to the TabBar. This would a viewController that is instantiated on tap and displayed within the TabBar.

Comment: presenting a `viewController` will, as it's name suggests, always present i.e. display it as the topmost `viewController`. The presented `viewController` can't be presented behind the presenting `viewController`. Besides, why do you want to do that anyways?

Comment: @staticVoidMan What I essentially want is to have the view change when I click a button. I'm trying to determine the best way to go about this and at this point I thought presenting a different viewController would work.

Comment: @BijanCronin so you want to show a new `viewController` without losing access to the `tabbar`? what is the purpose of this `viewController` & who is responsible for showing it; the `AppDelegate` or... ?

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes, I want to instantiate a new `viewController` and display it within one of the TabBar `viewControllers`.

Comment: @BijanCronin So which of the 3 tabbed `viewController` will display the new one? present won't work anywhere. have you thought about pushing one instead?

Comment: @BijanCronin Also, besides the main point, what kind of design requires you to have a `tabbarController` inside a `navigationController`? I mean, it's not wrong and some designs may do this but... are you sure this is what you want? One would generally have a `tabbarController` with tabs that are actually `navigationController`s having their own `rootViewController`s

Comment: @staticVoidMan I'll think about your suggestion and maybe implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom Tab bar which is a subclass of UITabBarController in my application. It has the following functionality for handling a scenario like yours.

UITabBarController holds an array of its child view controllers. Required (external) view controller is replaced with a currently visible view controller, which is at the selected index of UITabBarController, of that array. Then this updated array is set back to UITabBarController's child view controller array

```
func setSelectedViewController(_ externalViewController: UIViewController) {

    var arrChildViewControllers = self.childViewControllers

    if arrChildViewControllers.count > 0 {

        let selectedTabIndex = self.selectedIndex
        arrChildViewControllers.replaceSubrange(selectedTabIndex...selectedTabIndex, with: [externalViewController])

        self.viewControllers = arrChildViewControllers
    }

}
```